# Should Harold have taken Lillian’s surname upon marriage?

Tags: shrek

In *Shrek 2*, we are introduced to King Harold and Queen Lillian. At the end of the film, it is revealed that Harold was born a frog, which must mean that it was Lillian’s family who held the throne.

In *Shrek the Third*, we are introduced to Arthur Pendragon, who is Fiona’s maternal cousin. So Lillian’s surname must have been Pendragon as well.

Since Harold presumably didn’t have a surname before he died, should he have taken Lillian’s surname upon marriage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was Arthur specifically identified as the son of Lillian's brother, or of her sister? If the former, then he is a Pendragon and Lillian is not; otherwise then things are as you say.

Since this is a Hollywood production we're talking about, don't put too much faith in the producer's adherence to real-life rules of dynastic inheritance. Hollywood struggles to portray *itself* accurately, let alone anything requiring research.

Comment: Arthur is the son of Lillian's BROTHER, therefore Lillian's brother is Uther Pendragon.